# When MySQL set Id on Spring JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have Spring Application.Every Employee have Id.This is auto-generated by MySQL.
When I register Employee information in createEmployeeForm.html,I think it's Id is generated by MySQL.
But it's not working.Where I should fix it?

Model

```
@Table(name = "employees")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "emp_id", length = 8)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) // Id is auto-generated.
    private long empId;

    @Column(name = "emp_code", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String empCode;

    @Column(name = "emp_name", length = 20, nullable = false)
    private String empName;

    @Column(name = "emp_phone", length = 16)
    private Integer empPhone;
}
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class EmloyeeController {
    @Autowired
    EmployeeRepository empRepository;

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService empService;

    @GetMapping("/employees/new")
    public String initCreationForm(Model model) {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        return "view/createEmployeeForm";
    }

    @PostMapping("/employees/new")
    public String processCreationForm(Employee employee, EmployeeForm empForm, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "view/createEmployeeForm";
        } else {

            employee.setEmpCode(empForm.getEmpCode());
            employee.setEmpName(empForm.getEmpName());
            employee.setEmpPhone(empForm.getEmpPhone());

            empRepository.save(employee);
            model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
            return "redirect:/employees/show/{empId}"; // This code need Employee Id.
        }
    }

}
```

index.html

```
<a class="btn btn-default" th:href="@{/employees/new}">新規登録</a>
```

createEmployeeForm.html

```
<form th:object="${employee}" class="form-horizontal"
    id="add-owner-form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input
            th:replace="~{fragments/inputField :: input ('コード', 'empCode', 'text')}" />
        <input
            th:replace="~{fragments/inputField :: input ('名前', 'empName', 'text')}" />
        <input
            th:replace="~{fragments/inputField :: input ('電話', 'empPhone', 'text')}" />
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="従業員情報の登録" />
    </p>
</form>
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

error code

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Model has no value for key 'empId'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Model has no value for key 'empId'
```

folder structure
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJdMf.png

I use MySQL.And below is property file.
Before starting Spring Application,I type a command to create database in MySQL,then table is generated by application.

application.properties

```
### MySQL
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/library_system?useSSL=false&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Which Database are you using? Have you set the proper dialect in hibernate config? Please add your hibernate config also with this question.

Comment: Sure.I use MySQL and add property file.

Comment: can you try adding the hibernate dialect in your property file? spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

Comment: I solved.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem completely.

```
    @PostMapping("/employees/new")
    public String processCreationForm(Employee employee, EmployeeForm empForm, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "view/createEmployeeForm";
        } else {
            ...
            empRepository.save(employee);
            model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
            return "redirect:/employees/show/{empId}"; // This code is mistaken.        }
```

Return value should be redirect:/employees/show/" + employee.getEmpId();.

Answer (score -1):

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

I added this code.I can get employee Id.